# Including package data in Python with setup.cfg

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pipenv

I've been having some difficulty understanding how to set up package data with separate directories. I have a project as follows:

```
project_root/
    setup.cfg
    src/
        my_package/
            __init__.py
            command_line_interface.py
    data/
        data_my_package/
            schema.yaml
    tests/
        test_my_package/
            __init__.py
            test_command_line_interface.py
    Pipfile
    README.rst
    LICENSE
    noxfile.py
```

My `setup.cfg` has the following relevant sections currently:

```
[options]
packages = find:
package_dir =
    = src
include_package_data = True

[options.package_data]
py_repo_manager = data/*
```

However, when I use `importlib` to attempt to access resources like so:

```py
import importlib.resources

def read_schema_yaml():
    try:
        schema_content = importlib.resources.read_text("my_package.data_my_package", "schema.yaml")
        print(schema_content)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found or package not installed correctly")
```

I end up with a ModuleError.

What am I do doing incorrectly? Unfortunately I'm rather stuck, even after following the documentation as well as I could.

Thanks for any help!